# how to use LINQ to find an object in csv file

Tags: c#, .net, linq, object, csv

Hy,

I have a csv file like that

> user_name1,c:\photo\user_photo.jpg,0,0,0,0

in which every line refers a distinct object with own fileds separated from comma.

How I find a particular object knowing the user name? I use distinct user_names. And after that how I make that object, curent object that I use?

What i have done until now:

```
StreamReader sc = new StreamReader(@"C:\Player.csv");
String linie = sc.ReadLine();
while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(linie))
{
    string[] stringu = linie.Split(',');
    Player player = new Player(stringu[0], stringu[1], int.Parse(stringu[2]), int.Parse(stringu[3]), int.Parse(stringu[4]));
    players.Add(player);
    linie = sc.ReadLine();
}
sc.Close();
var query = players.Where(a => a.Name == label6.Text);
}
```

Sincerly,

Comment: What is the problem with the posted code?

Comment: Besides the fact that you don't handle commas in your fields, what are you trying to do that your code isn't handling?

Comment: You are mixing languages in your source code? Ugh. Itchy.

Comment: You are using LINQ in your code.  Since you accepted an answer dealing with query syntax for LINQ (as opposed to the method syntax for LINQ that you are using), you should realize that both syntaxes compile to the same IL.  See this MSDN article on query and method syntax for LINQ: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397947.aspx

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you tried something like

```
Player selected_player = from pl in players
                         where pl.Name == label6.Text
                         select pl;
```

?

Comment: This is no different than what the OP is currently doing.  Query and method syntax compile to the same thing.

Comment: Yep. I do not understand clearly what he is asking for... anyway, he is preparing the query but no using it, right?

Comment: But your answer doesn't help.

Comment: I don't think so. He want to get the object, and I'm getting it. But anyway, downvote for me :D

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use a library, which makes easy the use of CSV files with LINQ queries. Please look [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25133/LINQ-to-CSV-library).

Comment: I've used that library before and it's pretty good.  Note that it has an impact on performance and memory use, so it's not ideal for large files.  If your goal is RAD and no huge files or large performance requirements - it's the perfect tool for the job.

Comment: @TheSoftwareJedi thanks for sharing this with us. I haven't tested it this library against large files. So I haven't experienced this before.

Comment: Thank u Christos Paisios :-)

Comment: I worked for a large advertising firm and encountered 1-100 GB files regularly.  If I recall, this library wanted to load the whole file into memory, or kept already read rows in memory instead of using a cursor style design.  Again, it's good at what it does and I don't mean to indicate otherwise!  I'd use it again if it fit the bill. Luckily, I'm out of CSV land currently.

Comment: @TheSoftwareJedi sounds great - that you are out of CSV land. It's not a very happy place to be there. Thanks for your detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I'd suggest that for parsing a CSV file you don't roll your own field splitter. I'd suggest using something like the TextFieldParser (which can be used in C# by referencing Microsoft.VisualBasic).

Once you've created the parser you can use it to get the array of strings for each record represented by line in your application:

```
List<Players> players = new List<Players>();

var parser = new TextFieldParser();

while ( !parser.EOF )
{
   string [] playerFields = parser.ReadFields();

   // Create player from fields
   var player = Player.FromFields(playerFields);

   players.Add(player);
}
```

Now it really depends on whether you want to continuously query the players in the file, as if you do then getting an in-memory copy and using LINQ makes sense, else if you only want to query once then I'd simply do the check line by line.

Assuming that you do want to query multiple times then parsing the file and holding the values in a List or similar makes sense (assuming the file isn't ridiculously big).

Finally, if you has distinct user names then you could use the FirstOrDefault method in LINQ to give you the single player back that matches.

var player = players.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name.Equals(textBox.Text));

Or if you know that you have unique player names you could just store the whole lot in a dictionary....?

```
if ( players.ContainsKey(textBox.Text) )
{
  var player = players[textBox.Text];
}
```

Anyway, just some thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem you have at the moment, as far as I can see, it that you say you are looking to fetch "a particular object", but in your last line you are using `Where` which is going to return an `IEnumerable` containing one, none or many such objects. If you want to fetch one uniquely named object you should use `Single` or `SingleOrDefault`, e.g.

```
var myPlayer = players.Single(x => x.Name == label6.Text);
```

The answer you have accepted has merely converted your query from [method syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397947.aspx) to the equivalent [query syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397947.aspx) and introduced a compilation error by attempting to convert the resulting `IEnumerable<Player>` to a `Player`.

In anticipation of a problem you may be about to have, you might also want to look into [Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx) (you'll need to add a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll), which will allow you to parse a CSV in a more robust way, i.e. handle fields containing commas etc., using something like the following:

```
using (var parser = new TextFieldParser(filename))
{
    parser.SetDelimiters(",");
    while (!parser.EndOfData)
    {
        var p = parser.ReadFields();
        players.Add(new Player(p[0], p[1], int.Parse(p[2]), int.Parse(p[3]), int.Parse(p[4])));
    }
}
```